# Customizing ServiceStack Validation Response

Tags: c#, servicestack, fluentvalidation

I'm using `ServiceStack` `FluentValidation` for validating DTOs.

I know that I can customize the error message by using

```
public class HeaderItemValidator : AbstractValidator<HeaderItem>
{
    public HeaderItemValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(h => h.MCode).GreaterThan(0).WithMessage("Gotcha");
        ...
```

The point is that I would like to put the content of the validation inside a special object that partially include some of the request DTO data and a fixed error that I want the client to receive.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by creating your own validation filter.

In you AppHost Plugins Configuration:

```cs
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    ...
    // Add the Error Response Filter
    Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature { ErrorResponseFilter = ValidationErrorFilter });
    ...
```

Add to you AppHost:

```cs
// Return your own validation result format here
public static object ValidationErrorFilter(ValidationResult validationResult, object errorDto)
{
    // Loop through the validationResult create your own custom error response object.
    // return your response object 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works the way i wanted!